# PreparedStatement not executing!

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

So odd! :P

```
connection = appDatabase_.getDatabase().getConnection();
            PreparedStatement updateStmt = connection.prepareStatement
                    ("UPDATE " + getTableName() + " SET " + column
                               + " = ? WHERE " + ID + " = ?");
```

Got this chunk of code. After this comes some hard coded "set bytes" and "set int" statements.

And then an execute(). Pretty simple right?

Occasionally the prepared statement just fails to execute and the app acts very oddly (hard to explain how). Why and when would this happen? Maybe if the connection is closed?

Not sure what to think atm.

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you didn't show us your try/catch and I know java.sql classes are full of declared checked exceptions, my guess would be you're eating exceptions somewhere.